# Water in a glass on a rotating disc

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, water, centripetal-force, centrifugal-force

You put a glass of water on a record turntable and begin slowly increasing the speed. What happens first? Does the glass slide off, tip over, or does the water splash out?

I am particularly interested in the analysis when the glass is so placed that the central axis of the glass coincides with the central axis of the turntable.

Comment: Is the glass full, half-full, ...?  Is the turntable slippery, sticky, ...?

Comment: That information is not provided and it's acceptable to provide a solution/analysis while considering different combinations of the variables.

Comment: What is your analysis of this situation? What are you unsure about and why?

Comment: Is the question about the shape of the equilibrium surface (easy: high school level)? Or about how the angular momentum is transferred to the fluid (hard: caltech graduate fluids final exam).

Comment: @sammygerbil I am not able to understand if the glass will have a tendency to slip if it is perfectly centered along the axis of the turn table. My objective is to do the force analysis.

Comment: In which direction would it slip, if it is perfectly centred?

Comment: @sammygerbil I the table speed is increased slowly,  don't think it will slip as the centripetal force is symmetric across the axis and it the forces should cancel out leaving the glass perfectly centered.

Comment: You seem to be convinced that the glass will not slip if it is perfectly centred and the table speed is increased slowly. What if the table speed is not increased slowly? Is this the situation you are asking about?

Comment: @sammygerbil I do not have a physics-based explanation to suggest that the glass will slip if it is centered and speed increases slowly. On the other hand, increasing the speed suddenly will cause the glass to slip due to inertia of the glass.

Comment: You gave an explanation in the comments why the glass would not slip if perfectly centred and speed increases slowly. Why do you think this explanation will not work if the speed is increased rapidly?

Answer (score 0):

If the glass is centered, the surface of the turntable is level and not particularly slippery and the rotation speed is increasing gradually, the water will spin with the glass, with some lag, and the shape of its surface will be parabolic (the derivation could be found in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_argument)).

If those conditions are not met, all kind of things could happen and it would be hard to predict what exactly would happen because there are too many possibilities.

There is one more interesting case though, suggested by C.TowneSpringer:

> No matter where you put the glass, if it does not slip or tip over,
>   then the surface of whatever water remains will be a cookie cutter
>   section of a parabolic surface.

Comment: I agree. Will the glass slip even if the friction is zero? My analysis is that as the centripetal force acting on the glass is symmetric about the axis, irrespective of the friction (provided the surface is leveled), the glass should not budge from its position.

Comment: No matter where you put the glass, if it does not slip or tip over, then the surface of whatever water remains will be a cookie cutter section of a parabolic surface. The case of a tipping glass will depend on the shape and the static friction between the glass and the turntable.

Comment: @arpita_taurus If the friction is zero, the glass wound not slip, but it would not rotate either, so it is not a particularly interesting case.

Comment: @C.TowneSpringer Agree, good point.

Comment: @V.F. It's a good point that you mentioned. If there is friction between the glass and the turntable will the glass have a tendency to slip provided its axis is perfectly aligned with the table's axis?

Comment: @arpita_taurus If the speed is increased gradually, there won't be any slipping.